# GXT : How to customize TabPanel close context menu

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a GXT(3.0.1) TabPanel with many tabs.

This TabPanel has an out-of-the-box CloseContextMenu with 2 options :

- Close this tab
- Close all other tabs

In order to react to "close tab" events and be able to eventually cancel them, I use some BeforeCloseHandler.

**What I need :**

- When the user closes one tab, be able to display a confirmation dialog for this tab.
- When the user chooses to close all other tabs, display one unique confirmation for all tabs.

**The problem :**

The BeforeCloseHandler is called as many times as there are some tabs to close. So, I do not find any mean to make the distinction between *unique* and *massive* closes. I also do not find any mean to customize this menu.

Does anyone have a solution or am I trying to solve the wrong problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a cleaner solution provided by Sencha for this problem. Yes as you said if you see the implementation, `BeforeCloseEvent` is fired for every tab close, so you get a list of events. But there is a solution for that.

1.if you check how they create the closeContextMenu in TabPanel implementation you can see.

```
closeContextMenu.add(new MenuItem(getMessages().closeOtherTabs(), new SelectionHandler<MenuItem>() {
          @Override
          public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<MenuItem> event) {
            List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
            for (int i = 0, len = getWidgetCount(); i < len; i++) {
              widgets.add(getWidget(i));
            }

            for (Widget w : widgets) {
              TabItemConfig config = getConfig(w);
              if (w != contextMenuItem && config.isClosable()) {
                close(w);
              }
            }
          }

        }));
```

and also the `closeContextMenu` is protected so if you **extend** this `TabPanel` class you can set your own Menu instead of using the default one. Then you can add your own `SelectionHandler` and provide a relevant message to the user. For example as in the above code, you can show a prompt message before running the for loop which removes the tabs.

2.However context menus are not a great idea in web context. Can't you add a button may be next to tab panel and close all the tabs except selected one ? `TabPanel` has access to all the panels anyway.