# Removing the default close tab option of a GXT Tabpanel?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, tabpanel

So I'm using **GWT** + **GXT** and have created a **[GXT Tabpanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/TabPanel.html)** (see a similar demo/source displaying the basics of what I have [**here**](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basictabs) - be sure to go to the `tabs > basic tabs` section).

Once rendered, it's styling is shown like below:

[image]

Clicking on the anchors (small crosses in the top right-hand corner) results in that tab being closed. However, this is a piece of default behaviour I don't want, and would like to remove.

Say my TabPanel is simply:

```
panel= new TabPanel();
panel. ............... // Method to remove all tabs 'close tab' option.

panel.add(datacenterGrid, new TabItemConfig("Datacenter", true)); // Adding tab one
panel.add(clusterGrid, new TabItemConfig("Cluster", true)); // Adding tab two
```

Which [**Tabpanel method**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/TabPanel.html) could I use to simply remove the close tab option? (*Apologies if it's something simple and I'm being stupid, this area's new to me and I couldn't see any obvious method for it in the documentation*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the close button, just mark the tab as not closable.

You can do this with method: `TabPanel.add(Widget widget, TabItemConfig config);`

See setters on [TabItemConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/TabItemConfig.html)

Now, if you really want to customize the menu, I already asked [how to do it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591364/gxt-how-to-customize-tabpanel-close-context-menu)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in [`new TabItemConfig(String text, boolean close)`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/TabItemConfig.html#TabItemConfig%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) is whether or not the tab should be closeable. Just change

```
new TabItemConfig("Datacenter", true)
```

To

```
new TabItemConfig("Datacenter", false)
```

Or better yet

```
new TabItemConfig("Datacenter")
```

As the default behavior is false.